# Qt 5 QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters() not listing printers dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprinter

I am updating the printer list using availablePrinters(). But it fails to list the new printer added while running application. It is working fine with Qt 4.

The code can be seen below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinterInfo>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    while (1) {
        QThread::msleep(3000);
        qDebug()<<"List of printers";
        QList<QPrinterInfo> printerList=QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();
        foreach (QPrinterInfo printerInfo, printerList) {
            qDebug()<<printerInfo.printerName();
        }

    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Qt 5.1.1? Have you also tried "stable" after the 5.2 branching? Does it work though if you relaunch the application after adding the new printer?

Comment: it is working after relaunching the application.i didn't get "Have you also tried "stable" after the 5.2 branching?"

Comment: have you tried Qt 5.1.1? Next question if that does not work: have you tried to build it from the source (git/stable) branch?

Comment: i am using qt 5.1.1 still facing the same problem ,how to build it from source(git.stable) branch

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git Qt 5.0.X did not work either? Can you check that? Also, it does not work on any host platform, or just one particular?

Comment: it does not working on Debian Wheezy and Mac OSX Lion i did't tried windows

Comment: OK, I would try stable and if that does not work, I would report it. This printing feature has been moved to QPA with Qt 5 if I am not mistaken, so there can be regressions here and there.

Comment: I have the same problem on windows with Qt 5.1.1 code worked before with QT 4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug with the existing Qt version, and It got fixed on the next version